# why don't escape characters and regex work well with sed command?

Tags: bash, macos, sed

In my case, I wanna separate one line to words with sed command as below, which I though all should work.

```
[heping@Laputa:~]$echo "abc  def    gks       dps" | sed "s/\s+/\n/g"
abc  def    gks       dps
[heping@Laputa:~]$echo "abc  def    gks       dps" | sed "s/\s\{1,\}/\n/g"
abc  def    gkn       dpn
[heping@Laputa:~]$echo "abc  def    gks       dps" | sed "s/ \{1,\}/\n/g"
abcndefngksndps
[heping@Laputa:~]$echo "abc  def    gks       dps" | sed "s/ \{1,\}/:/g"
abc:def:gks:dps
[heping@Laputa:~]$echo "abc  def    gks       dps" | sed "s/ +/:/g"
abc  def    gks       dps
```

But actually, only one works.

```
[heping@Laputa:~]$echo "abc  def    gks       dps" | sed "s/ \{1,\}/:/g"
    abc:def:gks:dps
```

It seems that the `\s` character set and `+` special character in regex do not work well with sed command. And the `\n` is not recognized as a new line. Could anyone tell me why or give some clue. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed matches on Basic Regular Expressions while the meta-character `+` is from Extended Regular Expressions. The shorthand `\s` for the POSIX character class `[[:space:]]` will only work in some seds (e.g. GNU sed) as an extension. Similarly `\n` will only work as meaning "newline" in some seds while in any sed you can use a backslash followed by a literal newline character. Your use of double (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`) around your script is exposing it to the shell and so requiring extra backslash escapes - always use single quotes around strings or scripts unless you have a very specific need for double quotes (e.g. to let a variable expand) and only use double unless you have a very specific need for none (e.g. to allow globbing wildcard expansion).

To do what you want in any POSIX sed is:

```
$ echo 'abc  def    gks       dps' | sed 's/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*/\
/g'
abc
def
gks
dps
```

but this will work with GNU sed (note the `-E` to enable EREs for `+` - that is supported in GNU sed and OSX/BSD sed but of those 2 seds only GNU sed will support `\s` and `\n`):

```
$ echo 'abc  def    gks       dps' | sed -E 's/\s+/\n/g'
abc
def
gks
dps
```

Comment: Wow, your answer is more like a standard guide for a newbie like me! Thank you. I'll try to prefer single quote more than double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems. First of all, `sed` uses basic regular expressions by default, which do not recognise `+`. Use `-E` modifier for extended regular expressions, which do.

Second, `sed` doesn't recognise `\n`; but you can use [ANSI C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) to make `bash` understand it. However, if you just use `\n`, you'll just have a line break in your `sed` pattern, so you have to escape the line break to make `sed` use it literally; so you need `\\` for an escape, and `\n` for a line break, for a total of three backslashes.

Finally, `\s` as a character class is also not recognised by vanilla `sed` (but it is available on GNU `sed` that is used by Linux distributions). Use a literal space instead if you need compatibility with e.g. OSX (or `brew install gnu-sed`).

```
echo "abc  def    gks       dps" | sed -E $'s/ +/\\\n/g'
# => abc
#    def
#    gks
#    dps
```

Comment: Sir, thank you for your definitely clear explanation. But \s is not supported,  this is....is strange.

Comment: Let me rephrase: `\s` is supported in `gsed` (GNU `sed`, which is the default `sed` on Linux). It is not supported on older `sed` such as e.g. the one that comes with OSX by default. `sed` has a very, very long history. I'll edit it in...

Comment: OK, I got it. And one more question: why use the dollar and single quote? and especially why the dollar? I try to change it to  sed -E "s/ +/\\\n/g", and it becomes fucked up. : )

Comment: The $ thing is a bash instruction telling bash to replace the string `\n` (or any other escape sequence) in what follows between the `'`s with a literal newline before sed sees the script. So bash converts `\\\n` to `\<newline>` and then sed sees the whole command as `s/ +/\<newline>/g'` I wouldn't recommend wrapping a whole script that way, just do it when absolutely necessary for as brief a section as possible, in this case `sed -E 's/ +/\'$'\n''/g'` to just let the `\n` expand to a literal newline but not expose the rest of the script to the shell.

Comment: Thank you, sir. This is a new way to input a new line character into shell command line for me. Before you tell me this, I have used a single quote to input a new line character to shell for many years. Thank you so much. : )